# c#.net MS Access database without Access installed

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-4.0

Is it possible?

I've tried Google, but I must be searching the wrong key words and not getting an answer.

I have a small application only being used by 2-3 people that I want to store data in a database for. I can't install any SQL servers so I thought access would be the best option.

The computers it will be used on don't have Access installed either.

I'm using VS2012 Express .net4.0

Comment: `can't install any SQL servers` why exactly? Price?

Comment: They'll be run on computers that don't have admin privledges to install anything. The application is a standalone .exe

Comment: There's lots of help here:  http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007. If I were doing this today personally, I would use SQLite or SQL Server Compact instead.

Comment: There are other options - try [SQL Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) or [Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Comment: Will I be able to use SQLite/SQL Server Compact without having to install anything though?

Comment: The SQLite database is just a file.  It's driven by a DLL that does not require installation.  System.Data.SQLite is the wrapper that drives the DLL.  It sounds complicated, but it's not, and no installation is required; you just have to copy the needed files.

Comment: That does sound like a good way to go. Which .dll should I download? The computer I'm writting the application on is Windows 7 64bit, it will be run on a Windows XP 32bit though...

Comment: You can get precompiled SQLite binaries for .NET here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need is the connection string pointing to the access db with the right provider. Here's one that might work for you, just change the DB location to a shared place that the 2-3 computers can access:

```
var connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\BC207\test.accdb")
```

Comment: You need more than just a Connection object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course! but he's just asking if is possible to connect to an access DB in the scenario he presents, he's not asking for the current implementation so I just gave him breadcrumbs so he can find its way home :-)

Comment: No, that's good thanks. If there is something better that will fit my situation I'll galdly take it. But this does answer my original question.